# How to wrap <p> tag for dynamically appending span tags that is appending to class .description_cr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#preview_description').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('select').each(function(index, element{             
        $('.description_cr').append('<span>'+$(this).find('option:selected').text()+'</span>');                          });    
    });                                     
});
```

Comment: What result markup do you need? `<p><span></span></p>`?

Comment: `$('.description_cr').append('<p><span>' + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</span></p>');`?

Comment: @manasa: Would be great if you can share the DOM too.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
     $('.description_cr').append('<p><span>'+$(this).find('option:selected').text()+'</span></p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

```
$('#preview_description').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('select').each(function(index, element{         
        var pWrapped=$('<span>'+$(this).find('option:selected').text()+'</span>').wrap('<p/>');
        $('.description_cr').append(pWrapped); 
        });    
    });                                     
});
```

Even you could simply add `<p><span>..</span></p>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but if you want the newly created `span` to be a jQuery object then create as one, instead of just as text.

you create it like this:

`$('<span>')`

Then you have access to all the regular jQuery methods and properties of that new `span`. for example you can call `.append()` and then `.wrap('<p></p>')` on the `$('<span>')` like this...

```
$('#preview_description').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('select').each(function(index, element{             
        $('.description_cr').append($('<span>').append($(this).find('option:selected').text()).wrap('<p>')));                          });    
    });                                     
});
```